# MongoError :Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$or with aggregate pipeline

Tags: java, aggregation-framework

I am trying to write the logic with MongoDB aggregate pipeline, but it is failing with the below error. Below is my syntax of code but it is working with find operator. Could anyone help me with the aggregate pipeline . I am okay with find operator.I need same syntax with Aggregate pipeline . Appreciate any help.

```
Find operator code :working 

MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(database);
        MongoCollection<Document> collectionList = mongoDatabase.getCollection(this.collection);
      List  list = new ArrayList();
        document.append("$or", Arrays.asList(
                new Document()
                        .append("key", "S"),
                new Document()
                        .append("key", "P")
                ));
       List results = collection.find(document).sort(Sorts.descending("Period")).sort(Sorts.descending("_id")).limit(1).into(list);
        return results;
    
      

    Error Description :"message": "Command failed with error 40324 (Location40324): 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$or'' on server pl-0-eu-central-1.fpopz.mongodb.net:1032. The full response is {\"ok\": 0.0, \"errmsg\": \"Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$or'\", \"code\": 40324, \"codeName\": \"Location40324\", \"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1693589659, \"i\": 16}}, \"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"PqoVuUAo66TfpZJYVGfnyHuBz9A=\", \"subType\": \"00\"}}, \"keyId\": 7214365560476270596}}, \"operationTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1693589659, \"i\": 16}}}", 

  

    Query searchQuery = new Query();
           
       Document documentMap =  new Document();
            if (values != null && !values.isEmpty())
                documentMap.put("sample.value", values);
            if (color != null && !color.isEmpty())
                documentMap.put("sample.color", color);
             BasicDBObject projectFields=new BasicDBObject();
            projectFields.append("sample.value","$sample.value");
            projectFields.append("sample.value","$sample.value");
           List<Document> aggregate = new ArrayList<>();
            List<? extends Bson> pipelines;     
            pipelines = getDetailsAggregate(queryLimit, projectFields, documentMap);
            database = collection.aggregate(pipelines).into(aggregate);
            private List<? extends Bson> getDetailsAggregate(int queryLimit, BasicDBObject projectFields,Document documetMaps) {
            return  Arrays.asList(
                    new Document()
                            .append("$match", documetMaps),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$or", Arrays.asList(
                                    new Document()
                                            .append("key", "P"),
                                    new Document()
                                            .append("key", "S")
                            )),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$project", projectFields),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$sort",Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending(
                                    "Period"))),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$sort",Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending(
                                    "_id"))),
                    new Document()
                            .append("$limit", queryLimit)
            );
    
        }
```